# Perl: change in interpretation of shell symbols in system() invocation?

Tags: perl

Today I noticed that something changed in Perl, probably recently, in the way it runs shell commands. Could someone explain what has changed? I cannot find the answer myself and sadly we learned about this change in a hardest way possible. Some new users got an interesting contents of their new home directories...

I'm running a simple command/script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

system("ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*");
```

In Debian 11: `perl v5.32.1`, the output is just the contents of the `/etc/skel` (as expected):

```bash
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .face  .face.icon  .kshrc  .profile
```

But in Debian 12: `perl v5.36.0` the globbing `^` is ignored and the whole `/etc` is read, **which means `..` is not ignored**.

When I change `^` to the alternative symbol `!`: `system("ls -R /etc/skel/.[!.]*");`, it  runs as expected again.

The question is, what changed in Perl that it treats symbols `!` and `^` in `system()` invocation?

#### EDIT: 29.09.2023, 19:50

I did some tests on both servers and it looks like something in `dash` changed?

Debian 11: `dash Version: 0.5.11+git20200708+dd9ef66-5` (I do not see a `--version` flag in dash, so this is from APT).

```bash
root@s:~# dash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*'
/etc/skel/.bash_logout  /etc/skel/.bashrc  /etc/skel/.forward+spam  /etc/skel/.kshrc  /etc/skel/.profile
root@s:~# dash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[!.]*'
/etc/skel/.bash_logout  /etc/skel/.bashrc  /etc/skel/.forward+spam  /etc/skel/.kshrc  /etc/skel/.profile
```

Debian 12: `dash Version: 0.5.12-2`

```bash
[students] ~ ➽ $ dash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*' | more
/etc/skel/..:
a2ps.cfg
a2ps-site.cfg
adduser.conf
adjtime
aliases
aliases.db
alsa
alternatives

[students] ~ ➽ $ dash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[!.]*'
/etc/skel/.bash_logout  /etc/skel/.bashrc  /etc/skel/.face  /etc/skel/.face.icon  /etc/skel/.kshrc  /etc/skel/.profile
```

Kind regards, Kamil

Comment: You should compare the `sh` shells on the two systems rather than focusing on Perl.  Perl has absolutely nothing to do with the discrepancy, but one shell (`bash`?) accepts the non-standard `[^.]` globbing pattern as "not dot" while the other (`dash`?) treats it as a standard shell would, as "a circumflex or a dot".

Comment: In any Debian 11 or *your* particular Debian 11 installation? Looks like you switched `/bin/sh` to bash from dash

Comment: If all you're really using the scripts for is printing the output for the user to read it's probably harmless, but if you're doing anything to actually process the listed files you should probably try to do the file listing directly in perl with File::Find rather than relying on the behavior of either the shell or `ls`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation of `perl`'s `system()` function can be found with `perldoc -f system`. With perl 5.34, I find:

> `system LIST`
> `system PROGRAM LIST`
> Does exactly the same thing as `exec`, except that a fork is
> done first and the parent process waits for the child process to
> exit. Note that argument processing varies depending on the
> number of arguments. If there is more than one argument in LIST,
> or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the
> program given by the first element of the list with arguments
> given by the rest of the list. **If there is only one scalar
> argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and
> if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's
> command shell for parsing (this is "/bin/sh -c" on Unix
> platforms, but varies on other platforms)**. If there are no shell
> metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and
> passed directly to "execvp", which is more efficient.

Here, with `system("ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*")`, you're in the case where:

- one argument is passed
- the argument contains shell metacharacters, namely `[` and `*`¹ (`^` was a metacharacter in the Bourne shell as an alias for `|` for backward compatibility with the Thompson shell, but it's no longer in modern POSIX `sh`).

so that will actually be as if you had written:

```
system({"/bin/sh"} "sh", "-c", "ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*");
```

Which asks `sh` to interpret that `ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*` shell code in a child process and waits for its termination.

Except `ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*` is not valid POSIX `sh` code.

If you look at the specification of *Pathname Expansion* which in turn refers to [*Patterns Used for Filename Expansion*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) in the 2018 edition of the POSIX specification, and in particular the part about [*Patterns Matching a Single Character*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01), you'll find:

> `[`
> If an open bracket introduces a bracket expression as in XBD RE Bracket Expression, except that the **<exclamation-mark> character ( '!' ) shall replace the <circumflex> character ( '^' ) in its role in a non-matching list in the regular expression notation**, it shall introduce a pattern bracket expression. **A bracket expression starting with an unquoted <circumflex> character produces unspecified results**. Otherwise, '[' shall match the character itself.

In other words, to negate a set you use `[!x]`, not `[^x]`, and what `[^x]` does is unspecified, it could match the same as `[!x]` or either `^` or `x` (like with your `sh`) or anything as far as POSIX is concerned.

So if the behaviour changed for you, it's likely because your `sh` changed from one that behaved one way in that regard to one that behaved another way.

In the case of `dash` (the shell used on Debian, derived from NetBSD `sh` itself derived from the Almquist shell), there are a number of changes that affect or may affect the behaviour.

- [[EXPAND] Added configure --enable-glob and --enable-fnmatch options](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/commit/?id=) (2007), which added the possibility to compile `dash` so it uses the libc's `fnmatch()` and `glob()` to perform globbing instead of doing it internally (`dash`'s internal glob doesn't recognise `^`).
- [shell: Enable fnmatch/glob by default](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/commit/?id=7638476c18f2a8451b05d49f4e767ee1f98cfc17) (May 2020): that became the default (and may or may not support `^` as an alias for `!`, glibc does).
- [shell: Disable glob again as it strips trailing slashes](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/commit/?id=1f6fc2dc2f6e64248c43f94d4c52bb762c6fefce) (November 2020)
- [expand: Always quote caret when using fnmatch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/commit/?id=8f9cca055bc661c4c690a5f5e1ca71370d129bc3) (2022) after [this bug report](https://www.spinics.net/lists/dash/msg02158.html). Applies to `fnmatch()` as used in `case` statement, but the usage of `glob()` is still disabled by default.

That fix is not really relevant to your issue but note that, in turn, it introduces more bugs like:

```
$ string='\' pattern='[\^x]' dash -c 'case $string in ($pattern) echo match; esac'
match
```

So with dash linked to the GNU libc, there was a short window in between May and November 2020 where `^` would have been recognised as an alias to `!` and your 0.5.11+git20200708+dd9ef66-5 happens to land in the middle of it.

The reason why `^` (from regexp) was changed to `!` in globs is historical. As seen above `^` (initially that character was an upward arrow in ASCII, not a caret) was a pipe operator in the Thompson shell and Bourne shell, so `echo [^x]` would have been the same as `echo [ | x]` in modern `sh`.

That `^` alias to `|` was removed in the Korn shell and POSIX prohibits `^` from being treated as a pipe, but the Korn shell didn't change `[!x]` back to `[^x]` to try and preserve backward compatibility. Some other shells such as bash or zsh did (or shells like csh that never had a Bourne heritage baggage), so POSIX leaves it unspecified.

So, your code should have been:

```
ls -R /etc/skel/.[!.]*
```

To be valid `sh` syntax. Now there are still more problems with that code:

- I suppose the intention is to list the hidden files and directories (and their contents) other than `.` and `..` (which some shells still return in their globs though that's almost never desirable), but note that it misses files named `..foo` for instance.
- If there's no matching file, you'll get an error that the file called `/etc/skel/.[^.]*` doesn't exist.

`perl` is a much more capable language than `sh`, and it's also more portable as there's only one implementation, so instead of asking `sh` to find the hidden files in `/etc` to pass to `ls`, you could instead do it in `perl`:

```
@hidden_files = grep {!m{/\.\.?\z}} </etc/skel/.*>;
if (@hidden_files) {
  system "ls", "-R", @hidden_files;
}
```

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, space is also a metacharacter in `sh`, but it's not considered as such in that perl description; if there are no meta characters other than space, perl does the splitting on space by itself rather than calling `sh`.</sup>

Comment: Hmm, I would consider your asnwer as a definitive one, very detailed and informative -- and valid. I inherited the scirpts, which are much more complicated than the example I provided (it was just to illustrate the problem). They did work for years, despite not being POSIX compliant, but I see some discussion on the forumst and mailing lists, that `^` shoud/shouldn't be keep as a valid negation symbol.
The scripts apparently need some work, or probably should be rewritten in Python (people in our environment tend to use Python).

Comment: And I must admit that I saw a lot of `^`  in the scripts and on the Internet, and in the Bash manual and up to this point I too considered this as thing that "just works" :)

Comment: @Kamil If it were me, I would merely rebuild perl and this time tell `Configure` to use `/bin/bash` for the system shell rather than to use `/bin/sh` given that the latter points elsewhither now.

Answer (score 12):

It's not Perl that has changed, it is the default shell on your system. Perl's `system()` call uses `/bin/sh`. In recent Debian and Debian-derived systems, that is a symlink to `dash`, a basic POSIX shell. In older ones, and in many non-debian systems, it is instead a symlink to `bash`.

And, indeed, the two shells behave differently with `[^.]`:

```
$ dash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*' 2>/dev/null | wc
   2875    2572   45543
$ bash -c 'ls -R /etc/skel/.[^.]*' 2>/dev/null | wc
      5       5     103
```

You can also easily test this by doing:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo rm sh
$ sudo ln -s bash sh
```

And then running your Perl script again. You will see it behaves as you expect. Just remember to go back and undo the change:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo rm sh
$ sudo ln -s dash sh
```

Comment: :facepalm: shells change rarely, so I totallly forgot to check, what is the default shell. But I did check now, and in both installations the default is `dash` (symlink from `sh`), so the shell did not change. I did some more tests, and it looks like something in `dash` changed?

Comment: @Kamil Comparing the `sh` in the `debian:11` docker hub image with that of the `docker:12` image, I think this might be a correct assessment.  Both are `dash`, but they behave differently regarding the `[!.]` v.s. `[^.]` patterns (the newer version does not accept `^` as an alias for `!` in `[...]`).  The missing link is to find the changelog for `dash`.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at Debian's changelog now and see some globbing related things recently. https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/d/dash/dash_0.5.12-2_changelog

Comment: @Kamil Aha, they switch from using the system's `fnmatch()` implementation (which may treat `^` as `!` in `[...]`) to using a separate implementation of the routine, which presumably is stricter in its conformance to POSIX.  In any case, your Perl code should be using `!` for maximum portability.

Comment: Ping @terdon on this.

Comment: On Debian or derivatives, changing the `/bin/sh` symlink would be done with `dpkg-reconfigure dash`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Watch it: "From DebianSqueeze to DebianBullseye, it was possible to select bash as the target of the /bin/sh symlink (by running dpkg-reconfigure dash). As of DebianBookworm, this is no longer supported." https://wiki.debian.org/Shell . So assuming that's correct, the switch to Dash was in about 2011: it's amazing OP wasn't caught by this earlier and I can only speculate that the majority of systems he's responsible for had had the default shell changed.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, the default shell did not change. It is `dash` in all of my systems. The problem I discoverd and others kindly helped me to understand is that recently `dash` started to be more POSIX-compliant and dropped `^` as a negation symbol in globbing.

Comment: @Kamil Have you tried rebuilding perl and telling `Configure`  to use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh` for these purposes? This can help making migration from legacy systems significantly less rocky when moving from an **"sh is bash"** system to an **"sh is dash"** system if you have existing code that does bashy things like `sh -o pipefail` (and a great deal more) whenever perl "systems" out to "the system shell" by calling `system/exec` on a string not a list, pipe opens, and backtick operations). This way you don't have to override the installed symlink.

Comment: `sudo rm sh` is brave. An unexpected reboot just after it may render the system unusable. To avoid this: `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/shb && sudo mv /bin/shb /bin/sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Those symbols are interpreted by your shell, not by Perl.

What `system()` does is spawn `/bin/sh -c` with the entire command string as the argument. The shell is what interprets everything else inside that string – that's why it's called a *shell* command.

Unlike regular expressions (regex), `[^abc]` is not actually a standard syntax element in shell wildcards (globs) and writing it as `[!abc]` is the proper way. It just happens that some shells, such as Bash, accept both forms – but /bin/sh is not guaranteed to be Bash or to support any Bash-specific extensions; it is only required to support what POSIX requires out of a shell.

So on Debian, /bin/sh is nowadays much more likely to be linked to dash, a much more minimal shell (optimized for performance), although old installations *may* still have it linked to Bash as that used to be the default many releases ago. One of the differences is that dash does not support the alternative `^` symbol, only `!`.

(I also faintly remember something from last month about even Bash 5.2 behaving the same way when invoked "POSIX shell" mode? I can't remember now.)

---

If I might add, that's really not a good way of listing files through Perl. It has its own `glob()` function already! And if you want it to be recursive, use the standard `File::Find` module (or make a recursive Perl function). Even with system(), `find` would have avoided this issue as it doesn't need the `..` exclusion.

Comment: Yes, this is tnot the best way and just a simple example illustrating the problem (the real script is much more complicated).